# Need external (usb)Sound card suggestions that work with Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: jack, ardour, external-soundcard, rosegarden

I don't know if this is the right place to ask about this, but I'll give it a try.
I'm a linux user for a while now and I try to avoid opening Windows as much as possible. But for some things, I just have to. One of those things is recording. I play the guitar and I write music so I often need to record what I'm playing. Just in case it matters I'm planning to use `ardour` `audacity` `rosegarden` `hydrogen` and most of those nice programs that are widely known (linux known hehe). I need external usb sound card suggestions so I can do my thing on linux as well. Not too expensive please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lists of supported audio interfaces for Linux:

- http://wiki.linuxaudio.org/wiki/current_audio_gear
- http://wiki.linuxmusicians.com/doku.php?id=hardware_matrix

Comment: Too bad I didn't find that page before buying Scarlet 2i4. It does work fine. But I would like to check the rest of my options first. Ty m8.