# How do I get Ubuntu Studio recognize my M-Audio 2496 audio card

Tags: drivers, sound, soundcard

I installed Ubuntu studio and tried to make it recognize the audio card m-audio 2496. My efforts caused me to lose my system and now I've done a fresh install and was wondering how I should make the system recognize this card the right way.

Comment: - Run alsamixer in a terminal, press F6: do you see a soundcard named  "ice1712" ? If no, and if you have  an internal soundcard, disable it in bios and retest.    
- You also need to install "alsa-tools" package: in a terminal run `sudo apt-get install alsa-tools alsa-tools-gui` : this will give you a "envy24 mixer" in multimedia menu.

Comment: All plugins you mentioned are already installed. In the audio output of the ubuntu studio, the audio card appears. In another installation I did, or it showed. But now no sound. The sound bars stating that the music is playing on the plate but no sound appears.

Comment: What audio apps do you use ? It would be good to test with jack sound server  + Ardour (not sure this sound card needs jack,  but sure it works with it) . Also you can post alsa-info result  running this command in a terminal:   wget http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-info.sh -O alsa-info.sh && bash alsa-info.sh

Comment: Hey.. The log of also info is so big. Where I can post it? About the app, I am trying make a simple test with the Audacious.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem by doing the following process found in this post:

[Need external (usb)Sound card suggestions that work with Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/261595/need-external-usbsound-card-suggestions-that-work-with-ubuntu-12-04)

In my case, I had just a quite low volume. Other mixers were not showing up.

---

Try `gnome-alsamixer`. Here is what I do. I have integrated soundcard and Audigy.

1. Install Ubuntu Studio (not virtually).
2. Switch off the integrated soundcard in BIOS.
3. Launch terminal. Type `sudo apt-get install gnome-alsamixer`. After the program is installed type `gnome-alsamixer`.
4. Select "Audigy Analog/Digital Output Jack".
5. Enjoy

---

Note: I wrote Select "Audigy Analog/Digital Output Jack". You must select analog of your soundcard.